# How to resolve the Mac address for an IP address under kernel module developing?

Tags: sockets, ip, kernel-module, arp, netfilter

I want to build a tcp package in a kernel module and send it to another host by IP address using function dev_queue_xmit(skb). But I don't want to fill the Mac address manually by hand. The following is code for package producing.
 Some kernel functions call eth_rebuild_header(skb) to rebuild Mac header. However, in my case, it hangs my computer after being called. Google results answers that arp_find will crash the OS if the arp cache contains not entry for that IP address. But I'm sure the it exists in the arp cache as printed by shell command "arp -v".

```
static int build_and_xmit_tcp(char * eth, u_char * smac, u_char * dmac,
             u_long sip, u_long dip,
             u_short sport, u_short dport,
             u_char * pkt, int pkt_len,
             int syn, int ack, int fin,
             __be32 seq, __be32 seq_ack)
{
  struct sk_buff * skb = NULL;
  struct net_device * dev = NULL;
  struct ethhdr * ethdr = NULL;
  struct iphdr * iph = NULL;
  struct tcphdr * tcph = NULL;
  u_char * pdata = NULL;
  if(NULL == smac || NULL == dmac)
      goto out;

  if(NULL == (dev= dev_get_by_name(&init_net, eth)))
        goto out;
  skb = alloc_skb(pkt_len + sizeof(struct iphdr) + sizeof(struct tcphdr) + LL_RESERVED_SPACE(dev), GFP_ATOMIC);

  if(NULL == skb)
      goto out;
  skb_reserve(skb, LL_RESERVED_SPACE(dev));

  skb->dev = dev;
  skb->pkt_type = PACKET_OTHERHOST;
  skb->protocol = __constant_htons(ETH_P_IP);
  skb->ip_summed = CHECKSUM_NONE;
  skb->priority = 0;
    skb_set_network_header(skb, 0);
  skb_put(skb, sizeof(struct iphdr));
 skb_set_transport_header(skb, sizeof(struct iphdr));
  skb_put(skb, sizeof(struct tcphdr));

  pdata = skb_put(skb, pkt_len); 
  {
     if(NULL != pkt)
        memcpy(pdata, pkt, pkt_len);
  }

  tcph = tcp_hdr(skb);
  memset(tcph, 0, sizeof(struct tcphdr));
  tcph->source = sport;
  tcph->dest = dport;
  tcph->doff=5;
  tcph->seq = htonl(seq);
  tcph-> ack_seq= htonl( seq_ack);
  tcph->psh = pkt_len>0? 1:0;
  tcph ->fin = fin;
  tcph->ack = ack;
  tcph->syn=syn;
  tcph->window=__constant_htons (65535);
  skb->csum = 0;
  tcph->check = 0;
  iph = ip_hdr(skb);
  iph->version = 4;
  iph->ihl = sizeof(struct iphdr)>>2;
  iph->frag_off = 0;
  iph->protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
  iph->tos = 0;
  iph->daddr = dip;
  iph->saddr = sip;
  iph->ttl = 0x40;
  iph->tot_len = __constant_htons(skb->len);
  iph->check = 0;
  iph->check = ip_fast_csum((unsigned char *)iph,iph->ihl);

  skb->csum = skb_checksum(skb, iph->ihl*4, skb->len - iph->ihl * 4, 0);
  tcph->check = csum_tcpudp_magic(sip, dip, skb->len - iph->ihl * 4, IPPROTO_TCP, skb->csum);
  skb_push(skb, 14);
  skb_set_mac_header(skb, 0);
  ethdr = (struct ethhdr *)eth_hdr(skb);
//  memcpy(ethdr->h_dest, dmac, ETH_ALEN);
 // memcpy(ethdr->h_source, smac, ETH_ALEN);
  ethdr->h_proto = __constant_htons(ETH_P_IP);

//  arp_send(ARPOP_REQUEST, ETH_P_ARP, target, dev, saddr,
//       dst_ha, dev->dev_addr, NULL);
    eth_rebuild_header(skb);      // kernel hang....
  if(0 > dev_queue_xmit(skb)) {
        dev_put (dev);
        kfree_skb (skb);
  }
   return(NF_ACCEPT);

 out:
        dev_put (dev);
        kfree_skb (skb);
   return(NF_ACCEPT);
}


static int __init myhook_init(void)
{
   printk("=========insert module......\n");
   build_and_xmit_tcp(ETH_O, GWMAC_O, DMAC, in_aton(GWIP_O), in_aton(DIP), htons(8888), htons(DPORT), 
                    "", 0,
                    1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
}

static void __exit myhook_fini(void)
{
   printk("=========rmmod ......\n");
}

module_init(myhook_init);
module_exit(myhook_fini);
```

Google gives me some other solution. They say arp_ioctl can resolve the Mac address. However, the fact is that, arp_ioctl is compiled statically into vmlinuz, which is not exported as a symbol to other modules.

```
int arp_get(char *ifname, char *ipStr)
{
    struct arpreq req;  
    struct sockaddr_in *sin;  
    int ret = 0;  
    int sock_fd = 0;
    struct net_device * dev = NULL;
    printk("arp  ----  \n");
    if(NULL == (dev= dev_get_by_name(&init_net, ifname))){
        dev_put (dev);
        printk("error dev get \n");
        return -1;
    }
    struct net *net_arp = dev_net(dev);
    memset(&req, 0, sizeof(struct arpreq));  

    sin = (struct sockaddr_in *)&req.arp_pa;  
    sin->sin_family = AF_INET;  
    sin->sin_addr.s_addr = in_aton(ipStr);  


    strncpy(req.arp_dev, ifname, 15);
    ret = arp_ioctl(net_arp, SIOCGARP, &req);     // can't be called
    unsigned char *hw = (unsigned char *)req.arp_ha.sa_data;  
    printk("%#x-%#x-%#x-%#x-%#x-%#x\n", hw[0], hw[1], hw[2], hw[3], hw[4], hw[5]);
    return 0;
}
```

Maybe I need make a socket structure, and try some upper functions based on a socket. But how to do it...

kernel version : 2.6.32
os version: ubuntu 9.10
gcc version : 4.41

Comment: Which OS?  Which language?

Comment: @mikep "kernel version : 2.6.32 os version: ubuntu 9.10 gcc version : 4.41"

Comment: To try another way, I call the function "ip_route_input" get the route destination structure "dst_entry", but get error code -113 returned.

Comment: Function "ip_local_out"can deliver the skb out, but it need skb to provide struct "dst_entry" that is valid.

Answer (score 0):

```
int ip_xmit(struct sk_buff *skb) 
{
    struct iphdr *iph = ip_hdr(skb);
    struct tcphdr *tcph = tcp_hdr(skb);
    printk("dst is %d\n", skb->_skb_dst);
    int err;
//    err = ip_route_input(skb, iph->daddr, iph->saddr, 0, skb->dev);

    struct rtalbe *rt;

    {
        struct flowi fl = { .oif = 0,
                    .nl_u = { .ip4_u =
                          { .daddr = iph->daddr,
                        .saddr = iph->saddr,
                        .tos = 0 } },
                    .proto = IPPROTO_TCP,
                    .flags = 0,
                    .uli_u = { .ports =
                           { .sport = tcph->source,
                         .dport = tcph->dest } } };

        if (err = ip_route_output_key(&init_net, &rt, &fl))
            return err;
            printk("err is %d\n", err);
    }
    skb_dst_set(skb, rt);
    if(0 > ip_local_out(skb)) {
        printk("dev error\n");
        kfree_skb (skb);
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

function ip_route_output_key can obtain the route destination, and ip_local_out deliver the skb out.